# Please explain Interface<Interface> of Java generics

Tags: java, android, generics

As far as I know `<>` is used for strict type-checking.

In `ArrayList<MyClass> myArrayList;` for example, `myArrayList`will only accept objects of `MyClass` as elements and will also return the same. 
But I don't understand regarding `MyInterface<AnotherInterface> MyInterfaceobject;`. 
Here is a little code snippet

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity implements SplashMvpView {
@Inject
SplashMvpPresenter<SplashMvpView> mPresenter;
```

SplashMvpPresenter and SplashMvpView both are interfaces btw.

Link to the actual code: https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvp-architecture/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/framework/mvp/ui/splash

Please somebody explain in layman's term the whole `OneInterface<AnotherInterface> oneInterfaceObj;`  thing properly.
I'm a beginner.

Comment: It's just like with `ArrayList<MyClass>`. That's a class that "acts on" references of type `MyClass`, and specifically is able to store and retrieve them. Similarly, `SplashMvpPresenter` is some type (in this case, an interface, but that doesn't really matter) that "acts on" a `SplashMvpView`. What "acts on" means specifically is impossible to say just from the above -- it would depend on the methods on the SplashMvpPresenter. I would strongly suggest you go over a Java tutorial, as this kind of thing is hard to pick up piecemeal. It's really best to read a tutorial that walks you through it.